# Configure new commands in orgmode

Tags: org-mode, latex, init-file

I want to have custom commands for my documents in Org (which I export to Latex) for this I use `\newcommand`. I use a template that I load with `#+setupfile`, but if I define the new commands in that template I can't access them from my documents.

Command like this:

```
\newcommand\corazon[2]{\color{#1}{\heartsuit}\kern-2.5pt\color{#2}{\heartsuit}}
```

How can I make these commands global in my `.emacs` init file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change your `SETUPFILE` to read something like this:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand\corazon[2]{\color{#1}{\heartsuit}\kern-2.5pt\color{#2}{\heartsuit}}
```

or (much better IMO), you put all these things into your own style file, say `personal.sty`, which you put in a place where LaTeX can find it (check with `kpsepath tex` for places where LaTeX checks for such files and with `kpsewhich` to make sure that it can find the file) and then just add this to your `SETUPFILE`:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{personal}
```

That allows you to use those commands both in your Org mode files *and* in your LaTeX files and keeps the `SETUPFILE` neat and tidy. If you have questions about setting up your `personal.sty` file, you should ask in the [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).